# jQuery, select a dropdown item by exact value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found a snippet on the jQuery documentation about how to select an item in a dropdown menu.

```
$(element).find("option:contains(" + value + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Now this kind of works, except when I have two menu items that are similar. If my menu contains  2, 22, 222 and I set value to 2, then the last one will be selected. How do I specify an exact match rather than a contains?

Comment: Loop through the values and do a strict comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have a `value` attribute you could use that.

```
$(element).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Otherwise you'll need to filter the elements. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var optionsThatContainValue = $(element).find('option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === value;
});
```

Comment: The values is the database id, but I want to look for the text contained in the option

Answer (score 1):

`$(element).find("option[value='"+value+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');`

Comment: The value contains the database id, not the text value that is displayed

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == value){
         $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
```